# Notify consumer about new events in Kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a way to notify consumer about the new events being published to kafka topics which consumer has subscribed to while consumer is not actively listening? I know the question itself seems confusing but i was thinking if it is really necessary to have one process running continuously in order to consume messages. I think it will make consumer process easier if we know when the message is available to read.

Comment: There's no way for a consumer to be unpaused / not actively listening but also subscribed. Please explain your use case better

Answer (score 2):

Consumers read messages by polling the topic, so fundamentally, you must have a process running continuously. If the consumer does not poll within the value of the property `max.poll.interval.ms`, the consumer will leave the group. A hallmark feature of event-driven architectures is that consumers and producers are decoupled; the consumer does not know whether the producer even exists. Therefore, there is no way to know when a message is available to read without actively polling.

Comment: Yes I agree, I was just wondering if we could really avoid continuously polling for the new events to lessen the load on the server. Thank you for your answer.